# Нужны ли запятые после "человека" и перед "или"? Какой знак поставить между двумя "будет"?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Никто не может сказать за человека(,) будет он зарабатывать большие деньги или не будет(;) будет ли он работать и прилагать максимум усилий(,) или будет сидеть и ждать у моря погоды.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Отвечающие **нечетко определяют грамматику.**

*(1) Никто не может сказать за человека, (2) будет **он** зарабатывать большие деньги **или** не будет, (3) будет **ли** **он** работать и прилагать максимум усилий **или** будет сидеть и ждать у моря погоды.*

Это СПП с однородными изъяснительными придаточными: 1 — главное предложение, 2 и 3 — придаточные.

Связь между придаточными **бессоюзная**, поэтому между  (2) и (3) ставится **запятая**.

В придаточном (2) однородные сказуемые связаны одиночным союзом **ИЛИ**, запятая **не ставится**.

В придаточном (3) однородные сказуемые связаны  союзом **ЛИ...ИЛИ**, который для однородных членов считается **одиночным**, поэтому запятая также не ставится.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы поставил запятые везде, кроме последней. Перед "или" она не нужна. Точка с запятой разделила бы предложение на две части, а всё читается связно.

Answer (score 1):

***Никто не может сказать за человека, будет он зарабатывать большие деньги или не будет, будет ли он работать и прилагать максимум усилий или будет сидеть и ждать у моря погоды.***

***Будет зарабатывать или не будет*** - однородные члены, соединённые одиночным союзом "или" — запятая не ставится.

***...будет ли он работать и прилагать максимум усилий или будет сидеть и ждать у моря погоды.***

Здесь работает союз ЛИ...ИЛИ, который тоже соединяет однородные сказуемые, употреблённые в свою очередь парами:

***будет ЛИ работать и прилагать максимум усилий ИЛИ будет сидеть и ждать у моря погоды.***

**Если союз ЛИ...ИЛИ соединяет однородные члены предложения, то запятая перед ИЛИ не ставится.**

[Словарь-справочник по пунктуации](https://punktuaciya.academic.ru/369/%D0%BB%D0%B8..._%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8):

ли... или

...Запятая перед «или» не ставится, если «ли… или» соединяют однородные члены предложения.

*От света ли электричества или от волнения она слегка порозовела и кажется моложе. Л. Андреев, Христиане. Чувствительные дамы ахали от ужаса; мужчины бились об заклад, кого родит графиня: белого ли или черного ребенка. А.*

*Пушкин, Арап Петра Великого*.

**Запятая перед «или» ставится, если «ли… или» соединяют части сложного предложения, в том числе вопросительного.**

***В вашем случае союз ЛИ...ИЛИ соединяет однородные члены внутри простого предложения, находящегося в составе сложного.***